# Unable to add css in custom module's layout.xml

Tags: php, css, magento

What should I put instead of `<???>` to include my style on **every** page? (**not** on `<customer_account_create>` only)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layout>

 <???>
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><file>css/additional.css</file></action>
  </reference>
 </???>      

  <customer_account_create>
    <reference name='customer_form_register'>
      <action method='setTemplate'><template>address/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
  </customer_account_create>

</layout>
```

As suggested in similar Q&A, I tried without `<???></???>` or putting there `default`, `global` and `cms_index_index`, but none of them included the stylesheet.

Comment: As I wrote in question, `<default></default>` doesn't work for me, nor `<rwd></rwd>`. My layout file is in `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\mymodule_layout.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of pages you would like to load your css.

On all pages, use:

```
<default>...</default>
```

Only on product pages:

```
<catalog_product_view>...</catalog_product_view>
```

Only homepage:

```
<cms_index_index>...</cms_index_index>
```

Etc.

Edit: Make sure you did a layout update in your module config.xml file:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <company_module>
                    <file>mymodule_layout.xml</file>
                </hetnieuweweb_slider>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

Comment: As I wrote in question, `<default></default>` doesn't work for me, nor `<rwd></rwd>`. My layout file is in `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\mymodule_layout.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Try this (check your path):

```
<layout>
...
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/your-style.css</name><params/></action>
    </reference>
</default>
...
</layout>
```

May be you need Create file "local.xml" in app/design/frontend/default/[your-theme]/layout/

You can add handle with options to your layout:

```
<customer_account> <!-- any handle name -->
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/my_style.css</name><params/></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

And call it for example in:

```
<customer_account_create>
       <update handle="customer_account"/>
       ...
   </customer_account_create>
```

P.S. - `<default></default>` - should work!

Comment: As I wrote in question, `<default></default>` doesn't work for me, nor `<rwd></rwd>`. My layout file is in `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\mymodule_layout.xml`